# typescript dynamic property name mapped typed to function name

Tags: typescript

I have function that look like this:

```
function calc(a, b){
  return a + b
}
```

I can get its name

`calc.name`

and get the name 'calc' .

I also have create function

```
interface ICreateResult {
  [???]: string;
  'key': string;
}

function create(func): ICreateResult{
  return {
    [func.name]: 'some value',
    'key': 'some value'
  }
}
```

How can I make `typescript` validate

```
const obj = create(calc);
obj.calc // intellisense by typescript
obj.abc() // error
```

Comment: Would you like to send a function as a parameter to another function?

Comment: Can u add code sample? i can change from function to function param

Comment: Hi @haimma, can you explain the reason behind the whole question? What do you want to achieve? I think you're mixing up two things. You're trying to dynamically create a function (which is happening at runtime) and trying to have the autocompletion of your IDE for that dynamic function (which is happening pre-compile time).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would like to pass a function as a parameter to create. Lets try some changes to your code and transform to this:

```
function calc(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

function abc() {

}

type strictType = {
  funcSyntax: (a: number, b: number) => number
}

interface ICreateResult {
  funcCall: (a: number, b: number) => number;
  funcName: string;
  key: string;
}

function create(arg: strictType): ICreateResult {
  return {
    funcCall: arg.funcSyntax,
    funcName: arg.funcSyntax.name,
    key: 'some value',
  }
}
const crt = create({ funcSyntax: calc });
console.log(crt.funcCall.call(null, 4, 5));//9
console.log(crt.funcName);//calc

const crt2 = create({ funcSyntax: abc })//error
```

Comment: i need 'funcName' to be dynamic key, the actual function name.

i want to autocomplete the dynamic key, in the example
crt.calc should be autocomplete option.

the type returned should be
`
calc: whatever,
key: string
`
the name of function is he key in returned object.

Comment: What do you mean by autocomplete typescipt? Do you mean intellisense autocompolete the name of func and return it as key?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean.
i want intellisense, i want typescript to restrict me to the dynamic name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in current version of TypeScript.

See example:

```js
const x = (a: number) => a

type FnName = (typeof x)['name'] // string
```

`FnName` is infered as a `string` instead of literal string type `x`.